# Can I check http headers within a JAX-RS application using Interceptors?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

Should `@Context HttpHeaders` work within an `Interceptor`?

I've created a `RestfulClasses` class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` and annotated it `@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/api")` - all pretty standard stuff.

I also have a class, added to handle a particular path, which itself works fine. Trouble is I would like to check incoming HTTP headers, and using interceptors sounds perfect.

My interceptor class has an `@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders` declared, but within the `@AroundInvoke` method this property is null.

Should I expect this to work or am I missing something? Is there another way?

Comment: Why you wouldn't just add a Servlet Filter? [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) which could do the same thing and is a more standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way using interceptors: extend a base class that has a member:

```
 @Context protected HttpHeaders headers;
```

And an @AroundInvoke method that inspects the headers before any method gets called. It isn't exactly elegant though.

Artem's solution also works but I am new to the platform and had not encountered servlet filters before. It is more elegant although I still prefer annotations to web.xml markup...

Comment: If annotations are your only hang-up, see [Servlet 3.0's annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html). They let you [set up everything without any XML](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations).

Comment: Yep understood - I've just created a filter to do what I wanted (so much easier), and I'm about to jump up to read the annotations available since servlets v3. Many thanks for the help!